# Python create density layer/map WGS84

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm new to Python and struggling a little bit.  Basically I'm trying to create a geospatial density layer that can be in WGS84 with a weighted attribute and I want to "color" the attributes based on values.

So essentially I have lets say 10K records all with different locations and with a weight (basically the number of occurrences in this area).  Basically its' gridded up and I have a centroid lon/lat with a number of occurences.

For example.  If I have data related to the number of UCLA Graduates in the United States (gridded up by location) and I want to show these on a map that provides “COLOR” to indicate “density”

So my data would look like

```
lon,lat,total_graduates
23.24242, 42.242424,  212
24.22424, 43.242424, 86
```

I want to create a heat map/density, etc…  like

[image]

I only need the actual layer output and not the map.

My end result is to create a .PNG file that will be used in some of our GIS applications as "layers".

In some cases I could have a hundred thousand "boxes/grids" so I need something as fast as possible to render the image in WGS84.

I've been trying to do this with `matplotlib` but having no luck.  Any guidance would be helpful.

Comment: please provide your code and where you have  the issue

Comment: You probably want to use `basemap` or `cartopy`

Comment: or maybe `geopandas`

Comment: Have a look at https://datashader.org/